# How can wget be used to count number of pages on a website?

Tags: php, bash, wget

There are prospective client websites asking us for a re-design. Often when I ask, "How many pages is your website?" the answer I too often get is, "I don't know". It would be simple to count if there are 10 pages on their website, but these are larger websites with perhaps hundreds of pages.

Is there a way to count all the pages on a website without doing it manually? I know wget can be used to download pages from a website, but I don't want to download all their pages, besides that would just give me a collection of files not pages.

Is wget the solution to this? If so, how could it be used to count the pages of a website? If not with wget, is there another solution that would work? Remember, I don't have internal access to their website to do the count, it has to be done from the web. Or is counting the internal links equate to a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily count web pages if website is static or small.

but if website is too big like `StackOverflow` then you can use `Google indexing`.

Just goto google and search : `site:stackoverflow.com`

it returns the number of pages : `About 17,000,000 results`

You can put `site:` before each website and google show the total pages of that website